# maven-enforcer-plugin <requireProperty> -> <requireProperty>

Tags: pom.xml, required, parent-pom, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm using the maven-enforcer-plugin  and its working well.
I'm trying to understand how to make some properties required and some optional.
For ex. I have a property called useGit.

1. When useGit = true I wish that only the GIT properties will be enforced.
2. When useGit = false I wish that only the SVN properties will be enforced.
   Thanks!